# Remove some characters from an string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string, something like this: `rgb (255, 0, 0)`. And I want to remove every character inside it except numbers and the `,` (comma) character.

I have two questions based on this:

1. How to do that with Regex? (I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3210410/942659), but I don't know how to include the `,` (comma) sign into it...)
2. Is Regex the best method for this purpose? Or there is some other (better) methods?

*(Best = having best performance)*

Comment: "but I don't know how to include the , (comma) sign into it..." It doesn't take a lot of research and/or trial and error to find out.

Comment: Quick and dirty `string.Replace("rgb (", "").Replace(")","");`

Comment: You can use regexto extractthe numbers, rather than remove unwanted chars

Comment: Oded's answer was the best: `var clean = myString.Replace("01234567890, ".ToCharArray(), string.Empty);`, but he has deleted his answer. I don't know why...

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi I think Oded had it backwards.

Comment: Yeah, true, this will do the exact opposite of what you want.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes. interesting! lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regex is the easiest, surely:

```
Regex.Replace(s, "[^\d,]+", "")
```

will replace everything that is not a digit or a comma.

Answer (score 3):

Use the same approach as in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash/3210410#3210410) you referenced:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^\d,]");

str = rgx.Replace(str, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a very viable solution.

I would set my pattern to `(?<colour>(\d*), ?(\d*), ?(\d*))` allowing for optional spaces before each colour digit but does not limit to maximum 3 numbers per digit (a further tweak could rectify this).

You would then access the colour as a group.

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<colour>(\d*), ?(\d*), ?(\d*))");
Match m = pattern.Match(color);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["colour"].ToString());
```

Returns: 255, 0, 0

Comment: After viewing the question, I see performance was a requirement so I test the two and the results are not what I expected. Regex replace is faster up to 8 times! Full test code can be found at http://lewisharvey.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/regex-replace-vs-regex-match-and-group-performance/

Comment: Performance test results location changed: http://justcodesomething.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/regex-replace-vs-regex-match-and-group-performance/