# How to remove unknown formatted strings from string array?

Tags: c#, string, special-characters, stringcollection

I'm trying to remove strings with unrecognized characters from string collection. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: For example? How do you define "unrecognized characters"?

Comment: Characters that are not recognized are marked with diamond shape with "?" inside. I asume those characters are unicode formated, and ascii formation can't recognize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove strings that contain any characters you don't recognize:
(EG: if you want to accept lowercase letters, then "foo@bar" would be rejected")

1. Create a regular expression which defines the set of "recognized" characters, and starts with ^ and ends with $. For example, if your "recognized" characters are uppercase A through Z, it would be `^[A-Z]$`
2. Reject strings that don't match

*Note:* This won't work for strings that contain newlines, but you can tweak it if you need to support that

To remove strings that contain *entirely* characters you don't recognize:
(EG: If you want to accept lowercase letters, then "foo@bar" would be accepted because it does contain at least one lowercase letter)

1. Create a regular expression which defines the set of "recognized" characters, but with a `^` character inside the square brackets, and starts with ^ and ends with $. For example, if your "recognized" characters are uppercase A through Z, it would be `^[^A-Z]$`
2. Reject strings that DO match

Comment: Thanks, I allready used some regex to remove new lines and some special characters.

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove unknown formatted chars only?

Comment: @RadeMilovic I'm not sure what you mean by "remove unknown formatted chars only" - Do you mean to reject strings that are *entirely composed of* unrecognized chars?

Answer (score 1):

Since Array (assuming `string[]`) is not re-sized when removing items you will need to create new one anyway. So basic LINQ filtering with `ToArray()` will give you new array.

```
myArray = myArray.Where(s => !ContainsSpecialCharacters(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: OP has "array" in title, but "collection" in question body. Regardless, I like your answer.

Comment: I'm using the List<string> collection which allows me to remove elements easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Linq's [where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) method, along with a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx) containing the characters you're looking for. In pseudocode:

```
return myStringCollection.Where(!s matches regex)
```

Answer (score 0):

this does what you seem to want.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>()
{
    "one",
    "two`",
    "thr^ee",
    "four"
};

List<char> invalid_chars = new List<char>()
{
    '`', '-', '^'
};

strings.RemoveAll(s => s.Any(c => invalid_chars.Contains(c)));
strings.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

generates output:

```
one
four
```

Comment: No, I want to remove characters that are in other format and can't be recognized inside ascii formated string.

Comment: ahhh, gotcha. that part wasn't clear from your original post.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash) has some similar answers to what I think you are looking for.  However, I think you want to include all letters, numbers, whitespace and punctuation, but exclude everything else.  Is that accurate?  If so, this should do it for you:

```
char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();

arr = Array.FindAll<char>(arr, (c => (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || 
                      char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsPunctuation(c))));
str = new string(arr);
```

Comment: No, I want to remove characters that are in other format and can't be recognized inside ascii formated string.