# Remove all characters from String variable but letters

Tags: vb.net, string, variables, character, ascii

I want to write a function that removes all characters in a string variables but leaves only the letters.

For example, if the string variable has

> "My'na/me*is'S.oph&ia."

I want to display

> "My name is Sophia"

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `String` to a character array, like this:

```
Dim theCharacterArray As Char() = YourString.ToCharArray()
```

Now loop through and keep only the letters, like this:

```
theCharacterArray = Array.FindAll(Of Char)(theCharacterArray, (Function(c) (Char.IsLetter(c))))
```

Finally, convert the character back to a `String`, like this

```
YourString = New String(theCharacterArray)
```

Note: This answer is a VB.NET adaptation of an answer to [How to remove all non alphanumeric characters from a string except dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash).

Comment: The only problem is that is removes white-spaces, so the result is `"MynameisSophia"` instead of `"My name is Sophia"`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I understand, but the original string did not have white-space, so how can I preserve something that did not exist?

Comment: Ok, one step more missing, this does not replace the characters `'` and `*` with white-space as desired. However, i assume OP has simply provided a bad example.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to replace `'` and `*` with white-spaces and then remove all non-letters?

```
Dim lettersOnly = From c In "My'na/me*is'S.oph&ia.".
                  Replace("'"c, " "c).Replace("*"c, " "c)
                  Where Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) OrElse Char.IsLetter(c)
Dim result As New String(lettersOnly.ToArray())
```