# Find and count latter pair from a string by alphabetical order

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, count

I am working on a small project which is in C# where I want to find and count the latter pairs which comes in alphabetical order by ignoring spaces and special characters.
e.g.

```
This is a absolutely easy.
```

Here my output should be

```
hi 1
ab 1
```

I refereed [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string) post but not getting exact idea for pair latter count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would normalize the string to reduce confusion from special characters like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash):

```
string str = "This is a absolutely easy.";
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z]");
str = rgx.Replace(str, "");
str = str.ToLower();
```

Then, I would loop over all of the characters in the string and see if their neighbor is the next letter in the alphabet.

```
Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (str[i+1] == (char)(str[i]+1))
    {
        string index = "" + str[i] + str[i+1];
        if (!counts.ContainsKey(index))
            counts.Add(index, 0);
        counts[index]++;
    }
}
```

Printing the counts from there is pretty straightforward.

```
foreach (string s in counts.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s + " " + counts[s]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First I remove the spaces and special characters as you specified by simply going though the string and checking whether the current character is a letter:

```
    private static string GetLetters(string s)
    {
        string newString = "";

        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(item))
            {
                newString += item;
            }
        }

        return newString;
    }
```

Than I wrote a method which checks if the next letter is in alphabetical order using simple logic. I lower the character's case and check if the current character's ASCII code + 1 is equal to the next one's. If it is, of course they are the same:

```
    private static string[] GetLetterPairsInAlphabeticalOrder(string s)
    {
        List<string> pairs = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (char.ToLower(s[i]) + 1 == char.ToLower(s[i + 1]))
            {
                pairs.Add(s[i].ToString() + s[i+1].ToString());
            }
        }

        return pairs.ToArray();
    }
```

Here is how the main method will look like:

```
static void Main()
{
    string s = "This is a absolutely easy.";

    s = GetLetters(s);

    string[] pairOfLetters = GetLetterPairsInAlphabeticalOrder(s);

    foreach (var item in arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```