# How to remove characters and special notations from string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which can contain values both in `Character` and `Numeral` format along with some special characters like `<>`.So as per my requirement i have to remove these special characters and `Character` from the string.

Here is the string example..

```
string s = "O9668253";
string s2 = "<O>9668253";
```

And i need output like..

```
string s = "9668253";
string s2 = "9668253";
```

So how can i get this here .Please help me..

Comment: is it just alphanumeric characters you want to keep?

Comment: None of those are strings: are you missing some quotes?

Comment: Related: [Find and extract numbers from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use LINQ.  If I understand correctly you just want numbers:

```
string s = "<O>9668253";
string nums = new string(s.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

or if you want letters also:

```
string s = "<O>9668253";
string lettersAndNums = new string(s.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray());
```

if you want the non-digits, just negate it.  You'll have to write out the lambda expression:

```
string s = "<O>9668253";
var nums = new string(s.Where(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: +1 for not using RegEx

Comment: +1 and lol @rashleighp :) He was in luck this time.

Comment: If i have to take only `<O>` .How can i do that?

Comment: That depends. Do you want the first 3 characters, or anything between arrows, or just want to test if a string contains `<O>`...?

Comment: I want everything except `char.IsDigit` from the string

Answer (score 1):

similar question: [How do I remove all non alphanumeric characters from a string except dash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash)

Assuming you want to remove all non-numeric characters:

Replace [^0-9] with an empty string.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^0-9]");
str = rgx.Replace(str, "");
```

@Steve - thanks for pointing out the error

Comment: Did you read the question correctly? It seems to me that he wants to keep the numbers and discard the non-numbers.

Comment: ah right, i thought he just wanted to remove non-alphanumeric, will modify the answer.