# Removing all non letter characters from a string in C#

Tags: c#

I want to remove all non letter characters from a string. When I say all letters I mean anything that isn't in the alphabet, or an apostrophe. This is the code I have.

```
public static string RemoveBadChars(string word)
{
    char[] chars = new char[word.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = word[i];

        if ((int)c >= 65 && (int)c <= 90)
        {
            chars[i] = c;
        }
        else if ((int)c >= 97 && (int)c <= 122)
        {
            chars[i] = c;
        }
        else if ((int)c == 44)
        {
            chars[i] = c;
        }
    }

    word = new string(chars);

    return word;
}
```

It's close, but doesn't quite work. The problem is this:

```
[in]: "(the"
[out]: " the"
```

It gives me a space there instead of the "(". I want to remove the character entirely.

Comment: Very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-do-i-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash

Comment: you have space(null character) because the element in chars[] is zero if it is bad char. I think you need to shrink the string based on how many bad chars you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression would be better as this is pretty inefficient, but to answer your question, the problem with your code is that you should use a different variable other than i inside your for loop. So, something like this:

```
public static string RemoveBadChars(string word)
{
    char[] chars = new char[word.Length];
    int myindex=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = word[i];

        if ((int)c >= 65 && (int)c <= 90)
        {
            chars[myindex] = c;
            myindex++;
        }
        else if ((int)c >= 97 && (int)c <= 122)
        {
            chars[myindex] = c;
            myindex++;
        }
        else if ((int)c == 44)
        {
            chars[myindex] = c;
            myindex++;
        }
    }

    word = new string(chars);

    return word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that I could use Regex, but I was trying to do it without it, plus I don't understand Regex at all.

Comment: When there are characters to remove, then this function leaves null at the end. I think you should do something like this:

word = new string(chars, 0, myindex);

Answer (score 10):

The `Char` class has a method that could help out. Use [`Char.IsLetter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w(v=vs.110).aspx) to detect valid letters *(and an additional check for the apostrophe)*, then pass the result to the `string` constructor:

```
var input = "(the;':";

var result = new string(input.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c) || c == '\'').ToArray());
```

Output:

> the'

Answer (score 6):

You should use [Regular Expression (Regex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
public static string RemoveBadChars(string word)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z']");
    return reg.Replace(word, string.Empty);
}
```

If you don't want to replace spaces:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z' ]");
```

Comment: I've seen this before, but to be honest, I have no idea how that works and that's kind of why I avoided it. What does "[^a-zA-Z]" mean? To me it looks like senseless numbers, but the mean something and I can't figure it out.

Comment: how about apostrophe?

Comment: If you click on the link in my answer, you can see explanation to all the regular expression operators.

@V-SHY Opps, didn't read his question carefully enough, changed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static Regex badChars = new Regex("[^A-Za-z']");

public static string RemoveBadChars(string word)
{
    return badChars.Replace(word, "");
}
```

This creates a Regular Expression that consists of a *character class* (enclosed in square brackets) that looks for *anything that is not* (the leading `^` inside the character class) A-Z, a-z, or '. It then defines a function that replaces anything that matches the expression with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

This is the working answer, he says he want to remove none-letters chars

```
public static string RemoveNoneLetterChars(string word)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"\W");
    return reg.Replace(word, " "); // or return reg.Replace(word, String.Empty); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(word.Length), (acc, c) => acc.Append(Char.IsLetter(c) ? c.ToString() : "")).ToString();
```

Or you can substitute whatever function in place of IsLetter.