# Using regular expressions to exclude non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a log of strings formatted as the follow:
- SEGA E-r. Ata{{r}}i\n
- SEGA E-r. Atari\n

I want to obtain the final result of **SEGA E-r Atari** using regular expressions. Here's what I've written but it doesn't get me my expected result:

```
temp = re.findall('.*[^\{*][^\}*].*', 'SEGA E-r. Ata{{r}}i\n')
```

Here's what I get as the result:

```
['SEGA E-r Ata{{r}}i\\n']
```

Could you please help me with this?

Update:

The problem has been solved using the following line of code:

```
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]","",'SEGA E-r. Ata{{r}}i\n')
```

Comment: `s="SEGA E-r Atari"`. IOW, what's the rule?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you looking for all the places you can find that specific string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]","",'SEGA E-r. Ata{{r}}i\n')
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-do-i-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash) for reference.