# "A quotation mark delimiter is missing from the end of the query." error in WinCE PDA application

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, pushdown-automaton

In my WinCE PDA application, I am doing comparing the barcode value I scanned with the one in my database to generate a table.

I build the query like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        sb.Append("Select * from ToolsBar where BarcodeValue in (");
    }

    sb.Append("'" + listBox2.Items[i] + "',");

}

sb.Length = sb.Length - 1;
sb.Append(")");
```

And use it here:

```
cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // this is where the error came out  "A quotation mark delimiter is missing from the end of the query." 
reader.Close();
SqlCeDataAdapter ad = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sb.ToString(), con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ad.Fill(ds);
dataGrid2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

con.Close();
sb.Length = 0;
```

Comment: What is the content of sb?

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Comment: @kaihuacheng: What @Martheen means is what string does your `StringBuilder` hold?

Comment: I mean the actual content when you're debugging it.

Comment: ...@kaihuacheng we would like to see what your query is, as it's likely that is where the error is.

Comment: Debug the app, when the exception comes out, point your cursor to sb, paste the content here

Comment: @Martheen this is the loop                                                                       for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    sb.Append("Select * from ToolsBar where BarcodeValue in (");
                }
                sb.Append("'" + listBox2.Items[i] + "',");
              
            }
           
          sb.Length = sb.Length - 1;
          sb.Append(")");

Comment: Looks good at the first glance, but I really need you to just run the app until the exception comes out, then paste the content here. It really depends on the content of listbox2 which should be dynamic

Comment: Does one of your `listBox2.Items` values have a quote mark in them (e.g. `O'Connor`).  If they do, you'll need to escape them.

Comment: @Martheen   reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); this is the error comes out

Comment: When the error comes out, point your cursor to either cmd.CommandText or sb in Visual Studio

Comment: @BrendanGreen No, my list box only hold string value. no quotation mark

Comment: @Martheen sb = {Select * from ToolsBar where BarcodeValue in ('C1D10001}

Comment: As an alternative to Martheen's suggestion, since you seem to be having issues debugging, right before calling `cmd.ExecuteReader()`, do this `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(sb.ToString());`.  This will output the query to the output panel in Visual Studio.  Copy that and update your question with the query.  I know this has been asked multiple times, but quite honestly without it, you won't get this solved.

Comment: You are missing a closing quote.

Comment: Ah, see? Your loop doesn't seems to call sb.Append(")");

Comment: @BrendanGreen even i add System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(sb.ToString());  it still gives the same problem

Comment: What you posted is missing both a closing quote and closing bracket.  Are you sure that the loop you pasted in your question is correct?  Is there any other alteration done to the string builder between it getting created and the query executing?

Comment: @Martheen any suggestion on this issue?

Comment: Try changing the listbox append from 
 sb.Append("'" + listBox2.Items[i] + "',"); 
to sb.Append("'" + listBox2.Items[i].ToString() + "',"); 

I suspect the content comes from barcode scan, and either your barcode reading logic or the firmware doesn't strip the ending

Comment: On second though, it probably doesn't work since adding stuff to string should call .ToString implicitly

Comment: @Martheen yes. it does not work.  problem remains the same

Comment: Sigh. Try @BrendanGreen suggestion. MSDN says Length altering should pose no problem, but .NET CF got hidden gotchas everywhere. Also try to clear listbox items from non-alphanumeric using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-do-i-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate loop to build your query which removes the need to alter the string length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        sb.Append("Select * from ToolsBar where BarcodeValue in (");
        sb.Append("'" + listBox2.Items[i] + "'");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(",'" + listBox2.Items[i] + "'");
    }
}

sb.Append(")");
```

Comment: Does the content of sb still exactly the same? Try removing non-alphanumeric characters [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-do-i-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash)

Comment: even i get rid of non-alphanumeric , the error still is the same

Comment: Okay, that's literally impossible. The loop clearly must at least have a ")" even if there's nothing in listbox, yet your app just skip them. Try [step by step debugging](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/stepping-through-the-code/) to confirm that your loop did go through the last sb.Append(")") and don't went anywhere else before sending it to cmd.CommandText

Comment: Possibly related to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d98ab0f8-e1ce-4981-8e0d-42a454916890/appending-null-character-to-stringbuilder-results-in-incorrect-string?forum=netfxbcl). Normally you won't have null characters but with barcode reading involving non-managed call, you might have errand ending. Remove them using sb.Append("'" + listbox2.Items[i].Replace("\0", string.Empty) + "'");

Comment: vs2008 does not let me use Replace.

Comment: now my sb changed to sb = {Select * from ToolsBar where BarcodeValue in ('CD)}   but the problem is still the same

Comment: Thank you very much @Martheen,  Brendan Green  .   the problem is solved  .  You guys are great!

Comment: Wait, how? Did you just use Brendan's loop as it is, or do you change something else there?

Comment: @Martheen YES, i changed sb.Append(")"); to sb.Append("')");