# Matching multiple chars in string using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a the following path which I need to convert to URL.

```
string path = @"\\TestServer\User_Attachments$\Data\Reference\Input\Test.png";
```

I'm trying to replace the replace the special chars in this string. So

1. `\\ will become`//`with an`https`added at the front i.e.`https://`
2. `\` will become `/`
3. `User_Attachments$` will become `User_Attachments`

The final string should look like

```
string url = "https://TestServer/User_Attachments/Data/Reference/Input/Test.png"
```

To achieve this I've come up with the following `regex`

```
string pattern = @"^(.{2})|(\\{1})|(\${1})";
```

I then match using the `Matches()` method as:

```
var match = Regex.Matches(path, pattern);
```

My question is how can I check to see if the match is success and replace the appropriate value at the appropriate group and have a final `url` string as I mentioned above.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/CvWWOT/1) is the link to the regex

Comment: Why do you want to do it with regex? a simple `string.Replace()` chained would suffice and allow for greater readability of the final code...

Comment: @zaitsman I don't have to use regex, I just didn't know how to replace multiple values using `string.Replace()` hence why I went down this route. Would it be possible if you can provide an example please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above, i'd go for a simple `Replace`:

```
string path = @"\\TestServer\User_Attachments$\Data\Reference\Input\Test.png";
var url = path.Replace(@"\\", @"https://").Replace(@"\", @"/").Replace("$", string.Empty); 
// note if you want to get rid of all special chars you would do the last bit differently
```

For example, taken out of one of these SO answers here: 
[How do I remove all non alphanumeric characters from a string except dash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210393/how-do-i-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-dash)

```
// assume str contains the data with special chars

char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();

arr = Array.FindAll<char>(arr, (c => (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) 
                                  || char.IsWhiteSpace(c) 
                                  || c == '-'
                                  || c == '_')));
str = new string(arr);
```

Comment: You made it look so easy :/ can you elaborate on your comment please

Comment: You want to make sure the URL is encoded and you should also use HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode to make sure any special charcters

Comment: See the update to the answer -> you can use something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
string path = @"\\TestServer\User_Attachments$\Data\Reference\Input\Test.png";

string actualUrl=path.Replace("\\","https://").Replace("\","/")
```

Comment: You missed the `$` :)