# Let only some chars be typed in a datagridview cell

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to let only certain chars be added to a datagridview cell? 
like '1234567890'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches I know of that you can use for this. The first (and I think the best) is to use the CellValidating event on the `DataGridView` and check if the entered text is numeric.

Here is an example of that which sets the row error value too (with an additional CellEndEdit event handler incase the user cancels out of editing).

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,
        DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        string headerText = 
            dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;

        // Abort validation if cell is not in the Age column.
        if (!headerText.Equals("Age")) return;

        int output;

        // Confirm that the cell is an integer.
        if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out output))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText =
                "Age must be numeric";
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

    }

    void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the row error in case the user presses ESC.   
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = String.Empty;
    }
```

The second approach is to use the EditingControlShowing event and the attach an event to the cell's KeyPress - I'm not such a fan of this approach since it silently blocks the input of non numeric keys - though I suppose you could give some feedback (like a bell sounding) it just feels like more work compared to the other way.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.KeyPress -= TextboxNumeric_KeyPress;
    if ((int)(((System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)(sender)).CurrentCell.ColumnIndex) == 1)
    {
         e.Control.KeyPress += TextboxNumeric_KeyPress;
    }
}

private void TextboxNumeric_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    bool nonNumberEntered = true;

    if ((e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57) || e.KeyChar == 8)
    {
        nonNumberEntered = false;
    }

    if (nonNumberEntered)
     {
        // Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

One important note with this is be careful to remove the event handler on the control within the editing control showing method. This is important since the `DataGridView` reuses the same object for each cell of the same type, including across different columns. If you attach an event handler to a control in one textbox column, all the other text box cells in the grid will have the same handler! Also, multiple handlers will be attached, one for each time the control is shown.

The first solution came from [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc.aspx#Y554). The second came from [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ketaanhs/archive/2005/09/19/471117.aspx).

Comment: The second solution has two issues. The first is that once the Keypress event is replace in column one, it is in effect for all columns. The second is that it chains to itself, so that every time a key is pressed in column one the handler gets added again. so every keypress event happens multiple times.

Comment: @RichShealer Thanks, fixed that up by first removing the event. As I said, in this case this isn't at all my preferred method of doing this.

Comment: @David Hall - That fixed the multiple call issue, but leaves my first issue that all colums are filtered. I think to fix it you need to move the remove above the `IF` so that the handler is removed for the other cells that should not be filtered.

Comment: @RichShealer ah yes, forgot that other textbox columns will reuse that editing control. Now the handler is removed outside of the if.

Comment: @David Hall - I think this may be the only correct example on the Internet now!

Comment: @RichShealer lol! thank you for the constructive criticism - it is hard to give 100% correct code examples to questions like this, when one doesn't have to test the code for work, it is easy to miss the little things.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the datagridview to simply remove the invalid chars for the user, instead of issue an error message, use DataGridView.CellParsing().  This event only fires after you make a cell edit, and allows you to override what was entered.

For example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    // If this is column 1
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        // Remove special chars from cell value
        e.Value = RemoveSpecialCharacters(e.Value.ToString());
        e.ParsingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

For the RemoveSpecialCharacters() method, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120198/most-efficient-way-to-remove-special-characters-from-string) for some excellent methods of removing special chars from a string.

Comment: used **EditingControlShowing** event instead of **CellParsing** see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing(v=vs.110).aspx)