# c# winforms datagridview how to restrict cell input?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

What is the easiest way to prevent user to input comma value into datagridveiw cell ?
c# winforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687670/let-only-some-chars-be-typed-in-a-datagridview-cell][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687670/let-only-some-chars-be-typed-in-a-datagridview-cell

Answer (score 2):

**Try this** This will prevent entering comma when you try to type in the cells

```
 private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
 {
      e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
 }

 void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.KeyChar == 44)
      {
           e.Handled = true;
      }
 }
```

Don't forget to bind to the `EditingControlShowing` event of the DataGridView

**NOTE**

To precisely check and limit it for a control type you can check for the control type (for example for TextBox you can do this)

```
  private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Control is TextBox)
      {
          e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
       }
   }
```

Comment: We can check for e.Control type before adding the eventhandler.

Comment: check if (e.Control is TextBox), it will save variable declaration.