# Fix string for JavaScript in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a function that fixed non-printable characters in C# for JavaScript. But it works very slow! How to increase speed of this function?

```
private static string JsStringFixNonPrintable(string Source)
    {
        string Result = "";
        for (int Position = 0; Position < Source.Length; ++Position)
        {
            int i = Position;
            var CharCat = char.GetUnicodeCategory(Source, i);
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(Source[i]) ||
                CharCat == System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.LineSeparator ||
                CharCat == System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator) { Result += " "; continue; }
            if (Char.IsControl(Source[i]) && Source[i] != 10 && Source[i] != 13) continue;
            Result += Source[i];
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

Comment: I'd check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120198/most-efficient-way-to-remove-special-characters-from-string/1120248#1120248 for a regexp method as an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

I have recoded your snippet of code using `StringBuilder` class, with **predefined buffer size**... that is much faster than your sample.

```
    private static string JsStringFixNonPrintable(string Source)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(Source.Length); // predefine size to be the same as input
        for (int it = 0; it < Source.Length; ++it)
        {
            var ch = Source[it];
            var CharCat = char.GetUnicodeCategory(Source, it);
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch) ||
                CharCat == System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.LineSeparator ||
                CharCat == System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator) { builder.Append(' '); continue; }
            if (Char.IsControl(ch) && ch != 10 && ch != 13) continue;
            builder.Append(ch);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenating to the string, try using [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) which internally maintains a character buffer and does not create a new object every time you append.

Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append('a');
sb.Append('b');
sb.Append('c');
string result = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result); // prints 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Stringbuilder

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

and replace characters in-place, that should speed up things