# How can I check if a string has special characters in C++ effectively?

Tags: c++, string, whitelist, c-strings

I am trying to find if there is better way to check if the string has special characters. In my case, anything other than alphanumeric and a '_' is considered a special character. Currently, I have a string that contains special characters such as std::string = "!@#$%^&". I then use the std::find_first_of () algorithm to check if any of the special characters are present in the string.

I was wondering how to do it based on whitelisting. I want to specify the lowercase/uppercase characters, numbers and an underscore in a string ( I don't want to list them. Is there any way I can specify the ascii range of some sort like [a-zA-Z0-9_]). How can I achieve this? Then I plan to use the std::find_first_not_of(). In this way I can mention what I actually want and check for the opposite.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1120198/82705

Comment: @Sai Ganesh: different language there (C#)

Comment: C++ doesn't assume ASCII. It's even compatible with EBCDIC, in which A-Z is not contiguous.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
std::string  x(/*Load*/);
if (x.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890_") != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cerr << "Error\n";
}
```

Or try boost regular expressions:

```
// Note: \w matches any word character `alphanumeric plus "_"`
boost::regex test("\w+", re,boost::regex::perl);
if (!boost::regex_match(x.begin(), x.end(), test)
{
    std::cerr << "Error\n";
}

// The equivalent to \w should be:
boost::regex test("[A-Za-z0-9_]+", re,boost::regex::perl);
```

Comment: i know that i can do this but was wondering it i could mention the range such as [a-z A-Z 0-9 _] or ascii value range or something.

Comment: @Praveen: Added boost version.

Comment: regex go much simpler since the post: `#include <regex>; /*....*/ if(!std::regex_match(str_val,std::regex("[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+")) throw;`

Answer (score 4):

There's no way using standard C or C++ to do that using character ranges, you have to list out all of the characters.  For C strings, you can use [`strspn(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn) and [`strcspn(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn) to find the first character in a string that is a member of or is not a member of a given character set.  For example:

```
// Test if the given string has anything not in A-Za-z0-9_
bool HasSpecialCharacters(const char *str)
{
    return str[strspn(str, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_")] != 0;
}
```

For C++ strings, you can equivalently use the `find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of` member functions.

Another option is to use the [`isalnum(3)` and related functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalnum) from the `<ctype.h>` to test if a given character is alphanumeric or not; note that these functions are *locale-dependent*, so their behavior can (and does) change in other locales.  If you do not want that behavior, then don't use them.  If you do choose to use them, you'll have to also test for underscores separately, since there's no function that tests "alphabetic, numeric, or underscore", and you'll also have to code your own loop to search the string (or use `std::find` with an appropriate function object).

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that you need to consider is "is this ASCII only"?  If you answer is yes, I would encourage you to really consider whether or not you should allow ASCII only.  I currently work for a company that is really having some headaches getting into foreign markets because we didn't think to support unicode from the get-go.

That being said, ASCII makes it really easy to check for non alpha numerics.  Take a look at the ascii chart.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters

- Iterate through each character
- Check if the character is decimal value 48 - 57, 65 - 90, 97 - 122, or 95 (underscore)

Answer (score 4):

I think I'd do the job just a bit differently, treating the `std::string` as a collection, and using an algorithm. Using a C++0x lambda, it would look something like this:

```
bool has_special_char(std::string const &str) {
    return std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
        [](unsigned char ch) { return !(isalnum(ch) || ch == '_'); }) != str.end();
}
```

At least when you're dealing with `char` (not `wchar_t`), `isalnum` will typically use a table look up, so it'll usually be (quite a bit) faster than anything based on `find_first_of` (which will normally use a linear search instead). IOW, this is O(N) (N=str.size()), where something based on `find_first_of` will be O(N*M), (N=str.size(), M=pattern.size()).

If you want to do the job with pure C, you can use `scanf` with a scanset conversion that's theoretically non-portable, but supported by essentially all recent/popular compilers:

```
char junk;
if (sscanf(str, "%*[A-Za-z0-9_]%c", &junk))
    /* it has at least one "special" character
else
    /* no special characters */
```

The basic idea here is pretty simple: the scanset skips across all consecutive non-special characters (but doesn't assign the result to anything, because of the `*`), then we try to read one more character. If that succeeds, it means there was at least one character that was *not* skipped, so we must have at least one special character. If it fails, it means the scanset conversion matched the whole string, so all the characters were "non-special".

Officially, the C standard says that trying to put a range in a scanset conversion like this isn't portable (a '-' anywhere but the beginning or end of the scanset gives implementation defined behavior). There have even been a few compilers (from Borland) that would fail for this -- they would treat `A-Z` as matching exactly three possible characters, 'A', '-' and 'Z'. Most current compilers (or, more accurately, standard library implementations) take the approach this assumes: "A-Z" matches any upper-case character.

Comment: `isalnum` is optimized, it does not make a table-lookup, but it checks if the character is in a range: the code works like `('0' <= c && c <= '9') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')` where c is the character. It uses the fact that the characters (of a group like upper or lower letters or digits) are linear after each other in ascii. This is more efficient than regex(which needs a parser or an interpreter) or find_first_not_of.

Comment: @cmdLP: It's up to the implementation to decide how to implement it, of course. That said, here (for one example) is how it's implemented in libstdc++ for Linux: `return _M_table[static_cast<unsigned char>(__c)] & __m;`. (from: gcc/libstdc++-v3/config/os/gnu-linux/ctype_inline.h). And in libcxx, it's: `return isascii(c) ? (ctype<char>::classic_table()[c] & m) != 0 : false;`. (libcxx/src/locale.cpp). So, while there may be exceptions, it's usually table based.

Comment: @cmdLP: If you do know of one where it's based on comparison to ranges, however, I'd be interested in knowing what it is--I believe at the present time, that stands a good chance of being more efficient than a table lookup, but I don't know of any implementation that actually does it.

Comment: *"... the behavior of std::isalnum is undefined if the argument's value is neither representable as unsigned char nor equal to EOF."* As with all functions from `cctype`, their argument should first be converted to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the built-in C facility here. Iterate over each character in the string and check if it's `_` or if `isalpha(ch)` is true. If so then it's valid, otherwise it's a special character.

Answer (score 1):

The functions (macros) are subject to locale settings, but you should investigate `isalnum()` and relatives from `<ctype.h>` or `<cctype>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), my_predicate), s.end());

    bool my_predicate(char c)
    {
     return !(isalpha(c) || c=='_');
    }
```

will get you a clean string `s`.

Erase will strip it off all the special characters and is highly customisable
with the `my_predicate` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
#include <ctype>

for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    if( !std::isalpha(s[i]) && !std::isdigit(s[i]) && s[i]!='_')
          return false
}
```

The `isalpha()` function checks whether it is alphanumeric or not and `isdigit()` checks whether it is digit.

Comment: This worked without importing `ctype`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this, but don't want to go the whole hog and use regexps, and given you're test is for ASCII chars - just create a function to generate the string for `find_first_not_of`...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string expand(const char* p)
{
    std::string result;
    while (*p)
        if (p[1] == '-' && p[2])
        {
            for (int c = p[0]; c <= p[2]; ++c)
                result += (char)c;
            p += 3;
        }
        else
            result += *p++;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << expand("A-Za-z0-9_") << '\n';
}
```