# EDITED How do I split it up into char and int arrays

Tags: c++

I don't know what happened to the post but it must have happened on my first edit.

I got this info to go in and work when it was in separate files.  But I need it on one file.
I have looked in my text book and a bunch of other places but I can not find how to only get the text or characters out of the file.
I have got all the info into a single array but it looks like I will need to pull out each group piece by piece and put it where I want it but that looks slow, tedious and very susceptible to errors.

```
Johnson 85 83 77 91 76 
Aniston 80 90 95 93 48 
Cooper 78 81 11 90 73  
Gupta 92 83 30 69 87   
Blair 23 45 96 38 59  
Clark 60 85 45 39 67   
Kennedy 77 31 52 74 83

Bronson 93 94 89 77 97 

Sunny 79 85 28 93 82  
Smith 85 72 49 75 63
```

If this looks familiar it is the same assignment as my previous post, now I just need to figure out how to parse this info and use it again.

Comment: *I will even take getting this info into an array and copying cells into the right place* -- Read your own question, and pretend you're someone looking at how this is worded.  Does it portray any information as to what the structure is you're reading into?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. I have edited my question. It must have got messed up during submission.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you'll need to take your input as string value and check through it to find the beginning of the numerical characters.

only after having separated the alphabetical part of the input string from it's numerical part, you start creating your target arrays.

this might help: [How can I check if a string has special characters in C++ effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605282/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-has-special-characters-in-c-effectively)

/e: wording

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it. You could read it into a string and process it manually based on spaces. Or you could use `stringstream` to extract numerical values into `array/vector`. That however, still requires you to remove the name before you do it.

Here is a little code that reads the file content into an `unordered_map` which is essentially a `dictionary` as defined in other languages.

```
void read_file(const std::string& path) {
  std::ifstream in(path); // file stream to read file
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<double>> map;
  /*
   * map structure to hold data, you do not have to use this.
   * I am using it only for demonstration purposes.
   * map takes string (name) as KEY and vector<double> as VALUE
   * so given a NAME you can get the corresponding grades VECTOR
   * i.e.: map["Johnson"] --> [85, 83, 77, 91, 76]
   */

  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(in, line)) { // read entire line
    if (line == "") continue; // ignore empty lines
    int last_alpha_idx = 0; // name ends when last alphabetic is encountered
    for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
      if (std::isalpha(line[i])) last_alpha_idx = i; // get index of last alpha
    std::string name = line.substr(0, last_alpha_idx + 1); // name is from index 0 to last_alpha_idx inclusive (hence +1)
    std::string numbers = line.substr(last_alpha_idx + 1); // array values the rest of the line after the name
    std::stringstream ss(numbers); // this is an easy way to convert whitespace delimated string to array of numbers
    double value;
    while (ss >> value) // each iteration stops after whitespace is encountered
      map[name].push_back(value);
  }
}
```

You could read it into an array, the code will not change dramatically. I chose `string` as KEY and `vector<double>` as VALUE to form KEY/VALUE pairs for the dictionary (map).

As you can see in the code, it looks for the last alphabetic character in each line and takes its index to extract the name from the read line. Then it takes the rest of the string (just the numbers) and puts them into a `stringstream` which will extract each number individually in its inner loop.

Note: the code above supports having full names (e.g. "Johnson Smith 85 83 77 91 76").