# Remove '\' char from string c#

Tags: c#, trim

I have the following code

```
string line = ""; 

while ((line = stringReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // split the lines
    for (int c = 0; c < line.Length; c++)
    {
        if ( line[c] == ',' && line[c - 1] == '"' && line[c + 1] == '"')
        {
            line.Trim(new char[] {'\\'}); // <------
            lineBreakOne = line.Substring(1, c  - 2);
            lineBreakTwo = line.Substring(c + 2, line.Length - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added a comment net to the line I am wondering about. I want to remove all '\' chars from the string. Is this the correct way to to this? I doesnt work. All \ are still in the string.

Comment: `Trim(new char[] {'\\'})` will remove all \ characters from the start or the end.  It 'trims' them off.  As @user978511 states, you can use `Replace("\\", "")`.  (FYI, his use of the @ character means "take this string literally, without applying escaping rules")

Comment: None of the solutions below works for me...

Comment: Regex.Unescape()

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You could use:

```
line.Replace(@"\", "");
```

or

```
line.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
```

Comment: That's because Replace does not change the string itself, it returns the changed string. So you have to do like my answer, and write `line = line.Rep...`

Comment: These are not slashes. These are escape characters. They are used here to escape quotes. Consider using single quote instead of double quotes. You will not need slashes there then.

Comment: @PoiXen - In the string you have posted, `\"` is an escape sequence that lets `"` appear in the string. There are no back slash characters in it.

Comment: For an optimized solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120198/most-efficient-way-to-remove-special-characters-from-string

Comment: does not work for this "\"something://player.vimeo.com/video/27735162\""

Comment: @reza.cse08 Because there's no \ in you string, you have quote, which is escaped with \ - like \"

Answer (score 8):

to remove all '\' from a string, simply do the following:

```
myString = myString.Replace("\\", "");
```

Answer (score 8):

```
line = line.Replace("\\", "");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx) which basically removes all occurrences

```
line.Replace(@"\", "");
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply this?

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\\", "");
```

Comment: I think that needs to be either "\\" or @"\" doesn't it?

Comment: @BaliC Actually no. With one **"\"** you get parsing "\" - Illegal \ at end of pattern. .NET 3.5

Answer (score 6):

I have faced this issue so many times and I was surprised that many of these don't work.

I simply deserialize the string with Newtonsoft.Json and I get cleartext.

```
string rough = "\"call 12\"";
rough = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(rough);

//the result is: "call 12";
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to replace

```
string result = line.Replace("\\","");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
String sOld = ...;
String sNew =     sOld.Replace("\\", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Trim` only removes characters at the beginning and the end of the string, that's why your code doesn't quite work. You should use `Replace` instead:

```
line.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
         while ((line = stringReader.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
             // split the lines
             for (int c = 0; c < line.Length; c++)
             {
                 line = line.Replace("\\", "");
                 lineBreakOne = line.Substring(1, c - 2);
                 lineBreakTwo = line.Substring(c + 2, line.Length - 2);
             }
         }
```