# Cant remove the character \ from a string c#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a problem removing the char \ from a string containing multiple of these chars.

What i do is:

```
        string oldString = "{\"data\": [{\"name\": \"Test User Two\",\"id\": \"138488723160636\"}]}";
        string newString = oldString.Replace(@"\", "");
```

This does not work. On the other hand the following does work:

```
        string test = "fafeaeaetrt";
        string newString = test.Replace(@"a", "");
```

Besides this i have tried almost every solution in the following thread, nothing works:
[Remove '\' char from string c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383409/remove-char-from-string-c-sharp)

I know that there is something that i must have misunderstood about this :)

Can you tell me what and how i remove the character \ ?

EDIT:

But the JSON does not seem to work. I have a unit test that returns this json when the method _fbClient.Client.Get("/me/friends"); is called. See below

```
        dynamic friendListData = _fbClient.Client.Get("/me/friends");

        foreach (dynamic friend in friendListData.data)
        {
            friendsFacebookIds.Add(Convert.ToInt64(friend.id));
        }
```

When i try to access the data i get the exception message: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'data'

Thought it had something to do with the backslashes since this JSON validates to be valid using a online validator and removing the backslashes.

Comment: Your string doesn't contain any backslashes anyway. They're only in the source to escape the quotes.

Comment: Don'y replace anything, your json is correct. Try `var obj = JObject.Parse(oldString);`

Comment: First explain the "Does not work part". What happens, what do you expect to happen  ? ( copy paste some output.) However, your `oldString` does not contain any \ characters, the \ characters you have in the code are used to escape the double quotes.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and look at what's actually in `oldString` after that assignment occurs. The ```\``` character is used to escape the `"` so they appear literally in the string, rather than being used to "close" the string.

Comment: Add a line to output your string at the console to verify your string if the \" confuse you.
`Console.Out.WriteLine(newString);`

Comment: now that is a separate question - you need to use a JSON parser!

Answer (score 6):

There is no `\` character in your string, just `"` character that need to be escape with `\`.

Answer (score 3):

Those are escaping `"` by the compiler. They aren't in the string data itself. This is true even for the Visual Studio debugger - you might see them there.

If that didn't exist, the compiler would treat it as the end of the string literal.

You can [read up on C#'s string escaping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx).

Now if the string literal was prefixed with `@`, that would mean that an actual `\` is there.

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt work because in the `oldstring` `\` is used as escape sequence. So, there is no \ character in `oldstring`