# How to remove "\" from the string

Tags: c#, string, replace, slash

```
string value = "SELECT dbo.GetDefaultType(\"PartnerType\") AS default_answer;"
```

How can i remove "\" from the above string.

Get the ref from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383409/remove-char-from-string-c-sharp) and 
tried,

```
value.Replace(@"\", "");
value.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
```

Comment: The backslash is not there in the string value. It is only written in C# to tell the compiler that the following double quote belongs to the string value.

Comment: Look at the loupe in the debugger to see the real string which is: `SELECT dbo.GetDefaultType("PartnerType") AS default_answer;`

Comment: \ is the escape char, not the backslash char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you just see the value in the debugger and it shows the `\` from the string literal. If you click at the loupe you would see the real string value which is:

```
SELECT dbo.GetDefaultType("PartnerType") AS default_answer;
```

But to answer the question, if the string really was(including the declaration)

```
string value = "SELECT dbo.GetDefaultType(\"PartnerType\") AS default_answer;"
```

Then it could be initalized with this literal:

```
string value  = "string value = \"SELECT dbo.GetDefaultType(\\\"PartnerType\\\") AS default_answer;\"";
```

and you could really remove the backslashes with:

```
value = value.Replace("\\", "");
```

Answer (score 5):

The `\` isn't actually in the string it is only there to stop the double quotes from terminating the string literal early.

The string actually is `SELECT dbo.GetDefaultType("PartnerType") AS default_answer;`

`value` could just as easily been declared as

```
string value = @"SELECT dbo.GetDefaultType(""PartnerType"") AS default_answer;"
```

Where `""` inside the string is still only a single quote `"`

Comment: @NithinChandran We'll probably never know ... Cheer up, phuzi. Sometimes ppl dv because their significant other had a mood in the morning ...

Comment: @Fildor don't worry about me, it's just not constructive to down-vote without leaving a comment as to why 