# Verbatim string c# "'a\\\' b'"

Tags: c#, verbatim-string

I have string `'a\\\' b'`, i need make algorithm which will convert this string to string `'a' b'`

1. `'a\\\' b'` = > `'a\\' b'` => `'a\' b'` = > `'a' b'`
   How i can make it? Maybe c# have a method which can check , is char contains verbatim symbol or not?

Comment: Also see [How do I write a backslash (\) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532691/how-do-i-write-a-backslash-in-a-string)

Comment: Or, even better [Remove '\' char from string c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383409/remove-char-from-string-c-sharp)

Comment: Post code that shows your problem. People are constantly confusing string values, string literals, and escaped strings. We don't know which you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the backslashes with an empty string.

```
string example = "'a\\\' b'";

Console.WriteLine(example.Replace("\\", string.Empty)); // Prints 'a' b'
```