# What's the regular expression in .NET to remove special chars?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that can remove all the following characters from a string (and whitespace too):

```
~ % & \ ; : " ' , < > ? #
```

I tried it with following code:

```
var MyCleanString = Regex.Replace(InputString, @"[~%&\\;:,<>?#\s]", String.Empty);
```

and it is not working.

Comment: This seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120198/most-efficient-way-to-remove-special-characters-from-string

Comment: Have you tried the \W wildcard? It won't do whitespace though. You'll need \s for that.

Comment: is any character is particular not replaced?

Comment: @KentZhou, Does it need to be regex? String.Replace() or StringBuilder.Replace() is going to be faster and I don't see a compelling reason to opt for the regex solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The code below prints "abcdef", so I'm not sure why you would say that it doesn't work.

```
var InputString = "abc~%&\\;:,<>?# def";
var MyCleanString = Regex.Replace(InputString, @"[~%&\\;:,<>?#\s]", String.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(MyCleanString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static string RemoveChar(string input)
{

Regex r = new Regex("(?:[^a-z0-9 ]|(?<=['\"])s)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return r.Replace(input, String.Empty);
}
```