# Remove special characters from a string in JSTL

Tags: jstl

I have a string in jstl: 'Tall &. Big'
But I want this to replace with :'TallBig'.

I am trying to this by using fn:replace(String,'&',''); but I don't know how to mention multiple characters in this function to be removed.

Means I want to remove all special characters from a string.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120198/most-efficient-way-to-remove-special-characters-from-string. It does a similar if I understand the question.

Comment: You could do `fn:replace("Tall &. Big", " &. ", "");`

Comment: Max, this is not working what you suggested. I already tried this.

Comment: @CodeNoob , That is not in JSTL. I want to do this in JSTL

Comment: @Rahul: define "not working". Max's suggestion does what you want.

Comment: @JBNizet , Actually I am getting value from backend as 'Tall &. Big'. I want to make it 'TallBig', and want to use it as a id in html element. I tried fn:replace("Tall &. Big", "&", "")---working(removing &) But fn:replace("Tall &. Big", " &. ", "") is not working