# Unity 5 C# login system - www.data return 1 but it keeps going to else?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make a simple login system in Unity using C#, PHP and MySQL on localhost, but there is a problem. My code works like this:

In the php file, if the `username` and `password` matches the ones in the MySQL database, then echo 1. Else echo 0.

In the C# script file in Unity, the problem is in this part of the code:

```
if (www.error == null) 
    {
        if (www.data == "1") 
        {
            Debug.Log("Successful login/nLoading Scene...");
            StartCoroutine(GoToMenu());
        }
        else
        { 
            Debug.Log("Invalid account or password");
            print(www.url);
            print(www.data);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that my `www.data` is returning `1`, but it's skipping the condition `www.data == "1"` and going to else, where it print it's URL (I checked it, it's correct and functional) and it's data (equal to 1).

Comment: Sounds like a `c#` question, not `mysql`, or `php`..

Comment: try `if (www.data == 1) ` without the quotes

Comment: @mega6382 it returns an error: `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'.` Same to www.text

Comment: Could you give us the output of `Debug.Log(www.data);` ?

Comment: Try www.data.toString(). Your data is probably an int there.

Comment: `www.data` is obsolate, use `www.text`

Comment: @Thomas Debug.Log(www.data) output 1

Comment: @Isuka Thanks Isuka, but it gives the same result.

Comment: @Jerry using www.text gives the same result

Comment: It's very likely the result isn't exactly `"1"`. Try checking the result byte-by-byte, there's probably an end-line or another kind of whitespace in the results.

Comment: Maybe try it the other way : int.Parse(www.data) == 1

Comment: try what Luaan suggests. The best option to check it is to call somethibng like `(www.text.Length == 1)`

Comment: @JerrySwitalski and Luaan Thanks you two! I don't know why, but my `www.text.Length` is 2 if my echo is "1". If my echo is "11" my `www.text.Length` is 3 and so on.... If the echo is a int like 0,1,2 or 10, my `www.text.Length` will be 3. My echo doesn't have any white or blank spaces. My original problem is practically solved, but any of you know what this echo/www.text.Length problem really is?

Comment: Check my answer, maybe not what you are looking for but always something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last comment it is obvious that your PHP script is puting special character into the responce string.

The best way would be to ensure that you use same encoding on server and client and not adding the special characters.

But the fastest way to do this is to remove all of them on client side with method like this: ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120198/most-efficient-way-to-remove-special-characters-from-string))

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (char c in str) {
      if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '.' || c == '_') {
         sb.Append(c);
      }
   }
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

I am quessing that this special character is `"\n"`

Maybe this is not what you were looking for, but still it is some solution.

Comment: I tried this but my www.text.Length still 2. But you're right about the encoding. I saved my php file as ASCI and UTF-8, and the output on Unity for www.text.Length was 2 and 3 respectively. But using the same format and encoding for the C# and PHP files doesn't output www.text.Length as 1. Oddly, if i use RemoveSpecialCharacters(www.data) instead of www.data or RemoveSpecialCharacters(www.text) the login will succeed even if the Length is > 1. So your answer save my day, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (www.text == "1")
```

Or

```
if((int)www.text==1)
```